# Hidden field vulnerability

Tags: fortify

I have completed the source code scan (ASP) using the Fortify source code scanner.

Many hidden fields shows as a vulnerability. Like this one:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ToSave" value="0" />
```

How do I fix this issue to receive a passing test?

Thanks in advance
Mahesh

Comment: could you provide your form that your scanning, not just one input? Could you also provide a link to the software?

Comment: remove the hidden fields. You will get a passing test for sure

Answer (score 1):

**If this is application state and is not modified by the user:**

Passing application state thru the browser is always a bad idea and is one of the first things that the hacker will exploit.

If this is application state:  use proper ASP session management and save the session state on the server when you send the page to the user, and look up the session state on the server when the request is returned. In ASP.NET with C# you might do something like this:

```
Session(“ToSave”)  =  false;
```

When you send the response to the browser (e.g. send the page). Then, when you get the request back, because you’re using ASPs session management, session will have the state that you set.

**If this is not application state but is a hidden field that is calculated by JavaScript in the browser and is used on the server side:**

Please look at the design of the application. I do a ton of these code reviews and usually find that the application is doing something in JavaScript that should only be done on the server side. One example would be calculating the score of a test on the form putting that score in a hidden field and accepting that field on the server.  Another example would be calculating the ‘next’ page in a flow and putting a marker in a hidden field.   If you want to provide something like a score on the browser for user convenience use that's fine but make the official calculation (and decision, if applicable) on the server.

An attacker can easily see these values and create a request that would break your application, or worse, get the attacker something that he or she did not deserve.

**In any case hidden fields are cached on the browser** just as any pages are cached so it might not be wise to use hidden fields if they contain data you expect the user to not be able to see.

So, bottom line, I would agree that you shouldn't use hidden fields.